# Как убрать отступ снизу у картинки на устройствах меньше 540px?

Tags: css, img, media-queries

Всем привет, я новичок в верстке.

Сайт написан при помощи бутстрапа, проблема следующая:

У блока с подложкой `main_page` на устройствах меньше `540`, требуется убрать отступ снизу у картинки.

Посоветовали так прописать, но это явно не верно:

```
.main_page {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 10%;/*верно*/
  /*zoom: .8;*/
}

.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Само изображение

```
.img_mobile_right {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  right: 5px;
  width: 24.5%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Буду благодарна любым ресурсам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться [@media-правилом](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) для того что бы изменить значения у нужных Вам свойств при определенных размерах экрана устройства:

```
.main_page img {
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .main_page img {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Да, про media запросы знаю. Попробую Ваш вариант. Вот сам сайт https://career.smartsoft-vlg.ru/. Спасибо

Comment: А какое свойство отвечает за то, чтобы стили не пересекались на разных размерах экранов? Нашла только свойство all: initial. Но это обнуление стилей.

Comment: @NataliaFed  CSS это каскад, соответственно те стили что расположены ниже переписывают настройки тех которые выше. Если Вы сами не создадите такое пересечения то его не будет

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо.